# How to deploy a simple Hello World program to local Kubernetes cluster

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, docker-desktop

I have a very simple spring-boot Hello World program. When I run the application locally, I can navigate to http://localhost:8080/ and see the "Hello World" greeting displayed on the page. I have also created a Dockerfile and can build an image from it.

My next goal is to deploy this to a local Kubernetes cluster. I have used Docker Desktop to create a local kubernetes cluster. I want to create a deployment for my application, host it locally on the cluster, and access it from a browser.

I am not sure where to start with this deployment. I know that I will need to create charts, but I have no idea how to ultimately push this image to my cluster...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a kubernetes `deployment` and `service` definitions respectively.

These definitions can be in json or yaml format. Here is example definitions, you can use these definitions as template for your deploy.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: your-very-first-deployment
  labels:
    app: first-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: first-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: first-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: your-app
        image: your-image:with-version
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: your-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30180
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: first-deployment
```

**Do not forget to** update image line in deployment yaml with your `image name` and `image version`. After that replacement, save this file with name for example `deployment.yaml` and then `apply` this definition with `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml` command.

**Note that**, you need to use `port 30180` to access your application as it is stated in `service` definition as `nodePort` value. (http://localhost:30180)

*Links*:

Kubernetes services: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Kubernetes deployments: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

Comment: This worked for me. Although I had to push my docker image to a Docker Hub registry. Do you know whether there is a way to push and pull docker images from a local repository? I want this to be as local as possible.

Comment: @MikeIppolito You need to install artifactory repository such as nexus somewhere in your network: https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss 
after that you can use nexus as your docker repository and then push and pull your images from there

Comment: Thank you for your help - I ended up running a local Docker registry by following the instructions  [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)

Comment: I didn't know about that, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define deployment first to start , define docker image and required environment in deployment.